# YUI3 and JSON foreach

Tags: arrays, yui

I am receiving JSON from my PHP webservice like so:

```
{"success":false,"
 errors":{"x":"y"}
}
```

I am trying to loop through the `errors` array:

```
var data = Y.JSON.parse(response.responseText); //Parse the JSON above
Y.Array.each(data.errors, function(item, index){
  Y.log(item); //No Log in my console
});
```

The problem is that the function supplied to the `each` is never executed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that `errrors` is not an array. To be an array, it needs to be in this form:

```
{"success":false,"
 errors":[{"x":"y"}]
}
```

So, in my case, I had to iterate the object like so:

```
Y.Object.each(data.errors, function(item, index){

});
```